# React - I can't stop propagation of a label click within a table

Tags: reactjs

In the below example, I have a simple `<table>` with a checkbox inside it. I have click events on the td, tr and checkbox. I want to be able to click the checkbox and stop the bubbling to the td and tr. A simple "event.stopPropagation()" works great.

The problem is that if I want to connect a `<label>` to the checkbox using "htmlFor", the events won't stop bubbling when the label is clicked (even though it still works as expected with the checkbox itself is clicked). And even more strangely, the bubbling seems to happen in a weird order (as in Checkbox click is received last!).

Here's the code:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  func1(e){
    console.log('tr was clicked')
  },
  func2(e){
    console.log('td was clicked')
  },
  func3(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Checkbox was clicked')
  },
  render: function() {
    return <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr onClick={this.func1}>
          <td onClick={this.func2}>
            <input id="thing" type="checkbox" onClick={this.func3} />                                   
            <label htmlFor="thing"> label for checkbox</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

...And here's the Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/52785/
(View the console for the click events)

Comment: Clicking the label actually generates *two* events: One for clicking the label and one (implicitly) clicking the checkbox. You are only handling the checkbox, but not the label. Here is a simple HTML + JS example: https://jsfiddle.net/zh55jwzv/ (this is not react specific).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `label` doesn't have a click handler of it's own, and can't stop propagation, so when you click the `label` normal event bubbling takes place. This means that all the parent's event handlers are invoked in the correct order. In addition, because of the `htmlFor`, the `checkbox` click handler is also triggered, but not as part of the event bubbling.

To solve the problem, add a separate click handler to the `label` that only includes `.stopPropgation()` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5wzbb77L/)):

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  func1(e){
    console.log('tr was clicked')
  },
  func2(e){
    console.log('td was clicked')
  },
  func3(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Checkbox was clicked')
  },
  stopLabelPropagation(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  },
  render: function() {
    return <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr onClick={this.func1}>
          <td onClick={this.func2}>
            <input id="thing" type="checkbox" onClick={this.func3} />                                     
            <label htmlFor="thing" onClick={ this.stopLabelPropagation }>label for checkbox</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Updated your code at https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-wood-kuzh4 which worked for me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

Try wrapping with a span and add `evt.stopPropagation()` to span's onClick

```
<span onClick={evt => evt.stopPropagation()}>
   <input id="thing" type="checkbox" onClick={this.func3} />                                   
   <label htmlFor="thing"> label for checkbox</label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding an onClick on the label, with the same function binding is helping. Here's the code and the relevant JSBin: https://jsbin.com/caneqi/2/edit?html,js,output

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  func1(e){
    console.log('tr was clicked')
  },
  func2(e){
    console.log('td was clicked')
  },
  func3(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Checkbox was clicked')
  },
  render: function() {
    return <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr onClick={this.func1}>
          <td onClick={this.func2}>
            <input id="thing" type="checkbox" onClick={this.func3} />                                   
            <label htmlFor="thing" onClick={this.func3}> label for checkbox</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Although this works too, it would call the func3 method twice though...