# React, Why label not firing onChange for checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox

I feel like I've done this a million times, but possibly not with a mapping function. I have a collection of activities that I'm creating checkboxes with the code is as follows (`__map` is coming from Lodash by the way):

```
<div className="activity-blocks">
{
    __map(this.state.activities, (activity, i) => {
        return (
            <div key={ i } className="single-activity">
                <input id={ `register-activity-${ i }` } 
                    type="checkbox" className="register-multiselect" 
                    name="main_activity" checked={ !!activity.checked } 
                    onChange={ (e) => this.toggleActivity(e, activity.id) }
                />
                <label htmlFor={ `register-activity-${ i }` }>{ activity.name }</label>
            </div>
         )
    })
 }
```

My `onChange` handler looks like this:

```
toggleActivity(e, activityId) {
    let activities = { ...this.state.activities };

    __forEach(this.state.activities, (activity) => {
        if (activityId === activity.id) {
            activity = __assign(activity, { checked: e.target.checked });
            return false;
        }
    });

    this.setState({ activities: activities });
}
```

The handler works just fine, it's for reference mostly. My issue is that the label is not firing the handler. I have tested only the checkbox input with no label and it fires off the handler. Does anyone know why the label is not doing so?

More info: I've had this problem before but it usually turns out to be an id mismatch or something simple like that. I don't believe so this time.

---

**Edit**
I have deleted pretty much all the code from my file and incorporated Slawa's answer below and it still doesn't behave as expected. Here is the code including all imports, the class structure and all unnecessary code stripped out, including styles:

```
import React from 'react';
import __forEach from 'lodash/forEach';
import __assign from 'lodash/assign';
import __map from 'lodash/map';

export default class RegisterActivities extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            activities: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'label-1'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'label-2'
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'label-3'
                }
            ],
        }
    }

    toggleActivity(e, activityId) {
        const { activities } = this.state;

        const updated = activities.map((activity) => {
            if (activity.id === activityId){
                return {
                    ...activity,
                    checked: e.target.checked
                }
            }

            return activity;
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>what do you do?</p>
                <div>
                {
                    __map(this.state.activities, (activity, i) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={ i }>
                                <input id={ `register-activity-${ i }` } 
                                    type="checkbox" 
                                    name="main_activity" checked={ !!activity.checked } 
                                    onChange={ (e) => this.toggleActivity(e, activity.id) }
                                />
                                <label htmlFor={ `register-activity-${ i }` }>{ activity.name }</label>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Edit2**
I'm playing around and decided to replce `onChange` with `onClick` and now I'm able to click the actual checkbox to hit `toggleActivity`. Does anyone have an idea on why onChange isn't firing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to my question was found [on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957978/react-i-cant-stop-propagation-of-a-label-click-within-a-table). It turns out that my label's `onClick` event (behind the scenes of html/React, not coded myself) was bubbling up to the parent instead of handling the input. I needed to tell the label to stop propagating by doing `onClick={ e => e.stopPropagation() }`.

Comment: Well, you left out the part where React's handling of checkbox changes is actually a hack based on click, "to normalize browser differences", so if you have any ancestors with innocent click `preventDefault`, it interferes with React's checkbox change hack.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have an error in your toggleActivity function, activities is array and try to convert it to object, you can find my full solution of this problem here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wqyolw50vl

```
  toggleActivity(e, activityId) {
    const { activities } = this.state;

    const updated = activities.map( activity => {
      if (activity.id === activityId){
        return {
          ...activity,
          checked: !activity.checked
        }
      }

      return activity;
    })

    this.setState({ activities: updated });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for that catch. For some reason, I still can't figure out what's blocking my label from clicking the input. `toggleActivity` doesn't fire at all. Placing a debugger at the top of the function doesn't do anything.

Comment: in your example you do not update local state correctly, so there is no new checked value for you checkbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/wqyolw50vl - working example

Comment: I just edited with your example inside my file, removing all other code and it's still not working for me. 
**Edit** Also in an act of desperation, I completely copied your solution within the App class into my solution and still no clicks are triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue. It was driving me mad, but what my team and I discovered is there must be some bug with the `htmlFor` they tell you to use in the docs. We removed it from our checkbox prop and now it functions as expected with no weird side effects. I'm opening up a GH issue on it. I'll edit later with the link/update

Code that didn't work:

```
<label htmlFor={`${label}-checkbox`} className={checked ? "checked data-filter-checkbox" : "data-filter-checkbox"} >
  <input id={`${label}-checkbox`} type="checkbox" onChange={(event) => handleCheck(event)} value={label} name={label} checked={checked} />
  {label}
  <span>{count}</span>
</label>
```

Code I'm using now:

```
<label className={checked ? "checked data-filter-checkbox" : "data-filter-checkbox"} >
  <input id={`${label}-checkbox`} type="checkbox" onChange={(event) => handleCheck(event)} value={label} name={label} checked={checked} />
  {label}
  <span>{count}</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Great. The project I was working on was the only one where I've need to dynamically create checkboxes, so I would love to know progress on it. Who knows, maybe it was only a React 15 error and was fixed in 16.